# Why does radio buttons rapid click events get lost in Firefox using jQuery UI and KnockOut binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, knockout.js

To reproduce this problem, please refer to the following jsfiddle project http://jsfiddle.net/g4hkLubx/2/ in Firefox.

Alternatively use the following Javascript and HTML to reproduce the same problem:

```js
var ClickViewModel = function () {
    this.selectedValue = ko.observable("");

    this.selectValue = function (buttonId) {
        this.selectedValue(buttonId);
        this.result(this.result() + "\n" + this.selectedValue());
    };

    this.isSelected = function(buttonId) {
        return this.selectedValue() === buttonId;
    };

    this.clear = function() {
        console.debug("this", this);
     this.result('');
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ClickViewModel());
$("#radio-set").buttonset();
```

```html
<form>
  <div id="radio-set">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" data-bind="click: selectValue.bind($data, 'radio1')">
    <label for="radio1">1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" data-bind="click: selectValue.bind($data, 'radio2')">
    <label for="radio2">2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" data-bind="click: selectValue.bind($data, 'radio3')">
    <label for="radio3">3</label>
  </div>
</form>
<br><br>
<div data-bind="visible: isSelected('radio1')">
  <label for="text1_1">text1_1</label>
  <input type="textbox" id="text1_1">
  <br>
  <label for="text1_2">text1_2</label>
  <input type="textbox" id="text1_2">
</div>        
<div data-bind="visible: isSelected('radio2')">
  <label for="text2_1">text2_1</label>
  <input type="textbox" id="text2_1">
  <br>
  <label for="text2_2">text2_2</label>
  <input type="textbox" id="text2_2">
<input type="button" id="clear" data-bind="click: clear" value="Clear"/>
<br><br>
<textarea id="result" rows="50" cols="25"></textarea>
```

By clicking rapidly between options 1 and 2 or 2 and 3 in the sample, you will see that not all click events are registered in the TextArea at the bottom of the result pane.

I was not able to reproduce this behavior in Chrome or IE. We are using jQuery 1.11.0, jQuery UI 1.11.4 and Knockout 3.3.0 libraries.

Any idea what could cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you are mixing jQuery DOM manipulation with Knockout viewmodel code. Another problem is that your click binding should be getting a function, not the result of a function call.

It may be that some of your clicks are being interpreted as drags, because it's hard to click and keep the mouse still when you're trying to click in two different places in rapid succession.

```js
var ClickViewModel = function () {
    this.selectedValue = ko.observable("");

    this.selectValue = function (buttonId) {
        this.selectedValue(buttonId);
        this.result(this.result() + "\n" + this.selectedValue());
    };

    this.isSelected = function(buttonId) {
        return this.selectedValue() === buttonId;
    };

    this.clear = function() {
        console.debug("this", this);
  this.result('');
    }
    this.result = ko.observable('');
};

ko.applyBindings(new ClickViewModel());
$("#radio-set").buttonset();
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form>
    <div id="radio-set">
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" data-bind="click: selectValue.bind($data, 'radio1')">
        <label for="radio1">1</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" data-bind="click: selectValue.bind($data, 'radio2')">
        <label for="radio2">2</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio3" data-bind="click: selectValue.bind($data, 'radio3')">
        <label for="radio3">3</label>
    </div>
</form>
<br><br>
<div data-bind="visible: isSelected('radio1')">
    <label for="text1_1">text1_1</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text1_1">
    <br>
    <label for="text1_2">text1_2</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text1_2">
    <br>
    <label for="text1_3">text1_3</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text1_3">
    <br>
    <label for="text1_4">text1_4</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text1_4">
    <br>
    <label for="text1_5">text1_5</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text1_5">
    <br>
    <label for="text1_6">text1_6</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text1_6">
    <br>
    <label for="text1_7">text1_7</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text1_7">
    <br>
    <label for="text1_8">text1_8</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text1_8">
    <br>
    <label for="text1_9">text1_9</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text1_9">
</div>        
<div data-bind="visible: isSelected('radio2')">
    <label for="text2_1">text2_1</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text2_1">
    <br>
    <label for="text2_2">text2_2</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text2_2">
    <br>
    <label for="text2_3">text2_3</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text2_3">
    <br>
    <label for="text2_4">text2_4</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text2_4">
    <br>
    <label for="text2_5">text2_5</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text2_5">
    <br>
    <label for="text2_6">text2_6</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text2_6">
    <br>
    <label for="text2_7">text2_7</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text2_7">
    <br>
    <label for="text2_8">text2_8</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text2_8">
    <br>
    <label for="text2_9">text2_9</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text2_9">
</div>
<div data-bind="visible: isSelected('radio3')">
    <label for="text3_1">text3_1</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text3_1">
    <br>
    <label for="text3_2">text3_2</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text3_2">
    <br>
    <label for="text3_3">text3_3</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text3_3">
    <br>
    <label for="text3_4">text3_4</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text3_4">
    <br>
    <label for="text3_5">text3_5</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text3_5">
    <br>
    <label for="text3_6">text3_6</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text3_6">
    <br>
    <label for="text3_7">text3_7</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text3_7">
    <br>
    <label for="text3_8">text3_8</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text3_8">
    <br>
    <label for="text3_9">text3_9</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="text3_9">
</div>
<input type="button" id="clear" data-bind="click: clear" value="Clear"/>
<br><br>
<textarea id="result" rows="50" cols="25" data-bind="text:result"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments, especially the one about the click binding that should be a function and not the result of a function call. I have updated the jsfiddle sample code and added a new version with your suggestions, but the problem still exists in Firefox.  

Concerning the clicks being interpreted as drags, if you try dragging slowly from one radio button to the next (or previous) it does not register any event in the result TextArea. One other potential cause is the selection of text in the radio button being clicked, but I do not count those when it happens.

Comment: When I run your Fiddle in Firefox, if I click rapidly on a single button, all clicks register as events. If I try to go back and forth between buttons, some clicks get missed, but I think it is because my mouse is in motion during the click. If I ensure that my mouse is stopped to click, that slows me down, but all clicks to register. I get similar behavior in Chrome, so maybe my Firefox (on Mac) doesn't have the same problem as yours.

Comment: I do test with the latest version of Firefox in Windows. So it could well be that Firefox on Mac is different enough not to react the same. Good for you.